# MongoDB map reduce c# with stored js function

Tags: c#, mongodb

I saved my map and reduce function with db.system.js.save command,

I want to call in c# this function with map reduce 
same of

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
        MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
        MongoDatabase test = server.GetDatabase("test");
        MongoCredentials credentials = new MongoCredentials("username", "password");
        var databaseSettings = server.CreateDatabaseSettings("test");
        var database = server.GetDatabase(databaseSettings);

        BsonValue bv = test.Eval("GetSum(3,10)" );
```

is possible?

Comment: atleast the API says so. 
try passing the parameters separately though e.g. test.Eval("GetSum", 3, 10);

Comment: thanks its a ansver my question. But `BsonValue bv = test.Eval("GetSum",3,10 ); BsonValue bv1 = test.Eval(bv.AsBsonJavaScript.Code,3,10);` so test.Eval("GetSum", 3, 10); return js function and resend this function return result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer is;

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
    MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
    MongoDatabase test = server.GetDatabase("test");
    MongoCredentials credentials = new MongoCredentials("username", "password");
    var databaseSettings = server.CreateDatabaseSettings("test");
    var database = server.GetDatabase(databaseSettings);

    BsonValue bv = test.Eval("GetSum",3,10 ); // return stored js function
BsonValue bv1 = test.Eval(bv .AsBsonJavaScript.Code,3,10); // execute jsfunction
```